# Dovecot migration from static to passwd-file userdb driver

Tags: email-server, configuration, authentication, dovecot, migration

I have an email server set to use dovecot with virtual users :

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%n /etc/vmail/%d/users
}

userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=109 gid=111 home=/home/vmail/%d/%n
}
```

Now I need to set storage quotas for some users.  Apparently this isn't possible with the `static` driver, so I figured the simplest way to enable it would be to switch to `passwd-file`.  However I struggle to actually get it working.

Using the same `passdb` as above and

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%n /etc/vmail/%d/users
  default_fields = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/home/vmail/%d/%n
}
```

93.184.216.34
I get the following errors :

> dovecot: imap: Error: Authenticated user not found from userdb, auth lookup id=345505793 (client-pid=30121 client-id=1)
>
> dovecot: auth: Error: passwd-file(username@example.org,93.184.216.34,): user not found from userdb

I tried many variations and read many pages of the dovecot wiki, including [AuthDatabase/PasswdFile](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile), but I can't seem to interpret the documentation correctly.

**How do I transpose my `static` configuration into a `passwd-file` with minimal modifications ?**

`/etc/vmail/%d/users` files are of the standard form

```
user:{SHA512}…
```

And here is the output of `dovecot userdb` for these settings :

```
userdb {
  args = username_format=%n /etc/vmail/%d/users
  auth_verbose = default
  default_fields = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/home/vmail/%d/%n
  driver = passwd-file
  name = 
  override_fields = 
  result_failure = continue
  result_internalfail = continue
  result_success = return-ok
  skip = never
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrongly assumed that fields other than `user` and `password` were optional since `default_fields` would take care of them.

Actually, [the documentation](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile) states (emphasis mine)

> [The password file is] in the following format:
>
> `user:password:uid:gid:(gecos):home:(shell):extra_fields`
>
> For a password database it's enough to have only the user and password fields. **For a user database, you need to set also uid, gid and preferably also home** (see VirtualUsers). (gecos) and (shell) fields are unused by Dovecot.

So those fields are actually mandatory.  But since they are already set by `default_fields`, they can be empty :

```
user:{SHA512}pwd:::
```

I figured it by chance because the only working account was the one I was testing the quota on (using the per user `userdb_quota_rule` extra field)…

The `doveadm user user@example.org` was also very useful for debugging this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement your answer, you only need **two** colons after the password field for the `default_values` in `userdb` to be picked up.

```
/etc/dovecot/local.conf
-----------------------
passdb { 
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=CRYPT username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/passwd
}

userdb {
    driver = passwd-file
    args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/passwd
    default_fields = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/srv/vmail/%u
#    driver = static
#    args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/srv/vmail/%u
}
```

```
/etc/dovecot/passwd
-------------------
user@example.com:{SHA512}longPasswordHash::
```

Verification with `doveadm` gives also the home folder :

```
$ doveadm user user@example.com
field   value
uid     5000
gid     5000
home    /srv/vmail/user@example.com
mail    maildir:/srv/vmail/user@example.com/Maildir
```